# Bootstrap media queries: When to use min-width and when to use max-width?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I see some people declaring for example @media (min-width: 1200px) and other people declaring  @media (max-width: 1200px).

Do we need to declare both? If not what's the correct way to choose from the two?

Comment: Depends on your approach. A mobile-first approach means your base style is for smaller devices, and you progressively add styles when a `min-width` media query is reached, eventually up to your desktop size at >= 1200 pixels, for example. Vice versa for a desktop-first approach.

Comment: which is better? I think I built my website thinking desktop first so...I guess I should go for max-height, right?

Comment: Guessing you meant `max-width`, in which case: yes. That's also a valid approach. Ultimately, you need to make sure visitors on smaller devices can still use your site. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: oops! lol yeah I meant max-width. Thank you for your input!